# Prevent gallery screen to be show after taking picture from camera Android

Tags: android, image, android-camera, crop, android-gallery

I am facing a problem where in when I am trying to crop an image after it has picked from Gallery or Camera.

When I choose the image from gallery it gets cropped correctly without any problem. When I choose image from camera, the cropping is done properly but it shows me an "intermediate" screen as seen below without taking me directly to the crop screen.

[image]

**Note: Picture above is just for representation purposes to show the "intermediate" Recent screen.**

I don't want this "intermediate" Recent screen to be displayed. Instead I want to directly navigate to the crop intent. In apps like Whatsapp this behavior is not seen when someone changes his/her profile pic. It directly navigates to crop intent without showing "intermediate" screen.

Can someone help solve this problem?

Here is my complete code

```
 /**
    * This activity is used to display profile picture and update the same
    *
  */
  public class ChangeProfilePhotoActivity extends BaseActivity implements       
  View.OnClickListener {

private TextView mTvTitle;
private ImageView mBtnChangePhoto;
private ImageView mIvProfileImage;
public static final int CROP_PIC_REQUEST_CODE = 3;
public static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
public static final int GALLERY_IMAGE = 2;
public static final int IMAGE_CHOOSER_INTENT = 4;

int PERMISSION_ALL = 10;
String[] PERMISSIONS = { Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

//private Uri mImageUri;
//private Uri mCropImageUri;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_photo);
    initUI();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}


private void initUI() {
    mBtnChangePhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnChangePhoto);
    mIvProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

    mBtnChangePhoto.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnChangePhoto:

            //launch intent chooser
            getPickImageIntent(this);


            break;
        default:
            break;

    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case IMAGE_CHOOSER_INTENT:
                    if(data!=null){
                        String action = data.getAction();

                        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        //send image for cropping
                        doCrop(selectedImageUri);


                    }
                    break;
                case CROP_PIC_REQUEST_CODE:
                    if(data!=null){
                        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                        if(extras != null) {
                            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                            mIvProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void doCrop(Uri picUri) {
    try {

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PIC_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        // display an error message
        String errorMessage = "Your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}

public void getPickImageIntent(Context context) {
    Intent chooserIntent = null;

    List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();

    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    //startActivityForResult(pickIntent, GALLERY_IMAGE);

    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   /* String imageFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/crop_image.jpg";
    File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);
    Uri picUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile); // convert path to Uri
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri );*/
    //takePhotoIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);
    //startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);

    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, pickIntent);
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, takePhotoIntent);

    if (intentList.size() > 0) {
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1),
                context.getString(R.string.pick_image_intent_text));
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[intentList.size()]));
    }

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, IMAGE_CHOOSER_INTENT);

}

private static List<Intent> addIntentsToList(Context context, List<Intent> list, Intent intent) {
    try {
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            Intent targetedIntent = new Intent(intent);
            targetedIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            list.add(targetedIntent);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one. As a side benefit, you no longer have to worry about your app crashing due to the device not having a `CROP` activity, or that activity doing something that you do not expect.

Comment: Ok i will go for a library rather than an Intent if thats the case

Answer (score 3):

You're launching an intent.  That means you're handing control off to another app.  After that, you have no control over what happens.  Of course what happens will be different on every device, as some OEMs will use their own Gallery app or Camera app that may behave completely differently.

So no, there's no way to prevent them from doing that extra screen.  If you want total control, take the picture yourself via the camera or camera2 apis instead of calling an Intent.  (Note:  I don't actually suggest this, but if you want control its the only way).

Comment: I have experienced this in even major apps I thought it was a bug in OS

Comment: hi @Gabe Sechan: thanks for the information. any idea on how whatsapp then implements the same? When you change profile picture and select the camera option, it takes a pic and then directly navigates to crop screen. so is that camera screen basically an Intent or its done using Camera2

Comment: I don't use the app, so I can't tell you for sure. But if you see it doing something different than other apps on the phone, assume they custom built their own camera activity. From what I know of that team, it's totally something they would do.